# Select all in current layer and change stroke color. SVG

Tags: html, svg

i am doing a modification of svg-editor, specifically a mod of the method-draw implementation.

I am trying to create a function that if called automatically selects all objects and changes their stroke color.

i am able to call within my function this:

```
svgCanvas.selectAllInCurrentLayer();
```

which basically selects all items on canvas. However when i type below it the change stroke color function

```
svgCanvas.setcolor("stroke", "red");
```

it doesnt run the second command(the stroke change function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Method Draw/SVG Edit you would do:

```
svgCanvas.selectAllInCurrentLayer();
var selected = svgCanvas.getSelectedElems();
selected.forEach(function(el){
  el.setAttribute("stroke", "red")
});
```